# Unable to login to IPMI of Supermicro X9DRW-iF after f/w upgrade

Tags: ipmi, supermicro, bmc

I have a box with SuperMicro [X9DRW-iF](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C600/X9DRW-iF.cfm) mainboard. It has built-in BMC module, which provides IPMI interface and web-GUI for it.

After upgrading BMC firmware from `R 2.35` to `R 2.59` under web-GUI ("Network" and "IPMI" options was checked in "BMC Preserve Configuration" screen, "Preserve all Configuration" option was unchecked) BMC module restarted, accessible via both HTTP and SSH, but rejects my login attempts with default login and password (ADMIN/ADMIN) via both HTTP and SSH.

Before firmware upgrade there was only one user in IPMI - the default one (ADMIN/ADMIN).

Where did I go wrong? What should I do to restore access now? I only guess to re-flash firmware with some Linux stuff on local system on this box, without preserving any BMC config, to bring it generally to factory defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Re-flashing of BMC firmware is not required.

Having root access to Linux OS installed on this box I could repair IPMI access with [ipmitool(1)](https://packages.debian.org/en/wheezy/ipmitool):

```
$ sudo ipmitool user list 1
ID  Name             Callin  Link Auth  IPMI Msg   Channel Priv Limit
1                    false   false      true       NO ACCESS
2   ADMIN            false   false      true       ADMINISTRATOR

$ sudo ipmitool user set password 2 ADMIN
$
```

Now ADMIN/ADMIN works again.

But the question "Where did I go wrong during f/w upgrade?" still has no answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in IPMI tools; I always feel like I'm fumbling around but somehow get where I need.

You could try IMPITool in the host.  It may give you access to the configurations you need to restore remote access:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ipmitool/

Comment: Yes, I know about ipmitool(1), I mean it saying "some Linux stuff on local system on this box".

But I hope, there is some more friendly way to upgrade BMC fw without such pain, maybe?..

Comment: If you find something less of a pain, do share.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe too late ... BUT

This mothearboard shoud not be flashed with new IPMI fw, before BIOS is latest version, elsewere ipmi fails.

Comment: It depends. *SOME* versions of f/w for BMC of Supermicro mainboards needs you to flash latest BIOS f/w first, and it always mentioned in release notes. All other BMC f/w versions don't need that.